# MySQL: How to turn one database to read-only?

Tags: mysql

I need to turn one database into read-only, so I can clone the database and make schema modifications on the clone before we switch the application to the new database. I know the way to turn the MySQL database server into read-only, but that will make it impossible to do the schema change on the new cloned database.

I searched and didn't find any answer. I suspect there is no such feature. In that case, what would you recommend for upgrading a live database without pausing the service?

Answer (score 7):

You could revoke write access for specific users during this period.

Answer (score 4):

You could revoke update/insert/delete privilege on the account that is using that database.  If the application is logged in as root then you have bigger problems on your hands.

Answer (score -1):

Put read_only=1 in my.cnf and restart the MySQL server.  You will still be able to modify the schema as the superuser.